# svn commit missing file automatically

Tags: svn

I want to write a batch file that can auto commit missing file recursively.
how to write the batch command?
please helps.

Comment: What's a *missing file*? Something from another branch, where you'd `merge`? Something not yet committed, where you'd `add`? Which is it?

Comment: The linked image shows the files that I delete from local, but I want to commit it to SVN throught command line.
http://www.badongo.com/pic/11740167

Comment: @Linus: missing files are those that have been deleted locally but not using SVN delete.  @Arst: are you looking for a script that will SVN delete and then SVN commit all missing files?  Could you not SVN delete files instead of locally deleting them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following batch script should SVN delete and commit all files marked as missing (i.e. deleted locally but not using SVN delete):

```
@echo off
svn status | findstr /R "^!" > missing.list
for /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%A in (missing.list) do (
    svn delete %%A && svn -q commit %%A --message "deleting missing files")
```

Missing files are shown by `svn status` with the character `!`, for example:

```
!      test.txt
```

This script then uses [findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) to filter out any modifications other than missing files.  This list of missing files is then written to a file, `missing.list`.

Next, we iterate through this file, using `tokens=2 delims=` to remove the `!` from the lines in the file, leaving us with (hopefully) just the filename.  Once we have the filename, we pass it to `svn delete` and then `svn commit`.  Feel free to change the contents of the message.

Please note that I have **not** tested this script.  In particular, I don't know what happens if one of the files you wish to commit has a space in its path, or what happens if you encounter a conflict part of the way through.  It may be better to replace `svn delete` and `svn commit` with `echo svn delete` and `echo svn commit`, so that you can see what this script is about to do before you let it loose on your repository.

Comment: thx for the answer. Is that possible to don't write into file?

Comment: I'm not sure if it you can use a `for` loop on the output of a command.  I seem to remember trying and failing to achieve this before.  That's why I wrote the output of the line before the `for` loop into a file.  If you don't want the `missing.list` file left hanging around, you can always add `del missing.list` to the end of the batch script.

Comment: for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %i in (`svn st ^| findstr /R "^!"`) do svn del "%i"

Comment: Accoring to ur post, I modified it as above.

Comment: @Arst: that does indeed seem to be how you run a `for` loop on the output of a command.  Looks like your batch-fu is better than mine :)

Comment: This seems to only take the first part of the filename, if the filename contains spaces.

Answer (score 11):

Use `svn rm $( svn status | sed -e '/^!/!d' -e 's/^!//' )`

See http://geryit.com/blog/2011/03/command-line-subversion-practices/ for more command line subversion

Comment: Anyone know.. what is sed?

Comment: it's a Unix command, this will not work on Windows unless you use Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

just execute the following commands in the root of your working copy:

```
    svn add . --force
    svn commit -m"Adding missing files"
```

Comment: This adds new files but doesn't 'delete' files from SVN that have been removed from the working copy.

Answer (score 0):

Arst,

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %i in (svn st ^| findstr /R "^!") do svn del "%i"
```

is almost right, but you forgot to wrap the parenthesized commands with back ticks:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %i in (`svn st ^| findstr /R "^!"`) do svn del "%i"
```

Thanks for the concise command, in any case.

Comment: @stevek_mcc Good catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made little change for my work..

```
@echo off

cd c:\project

for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %%i in (\`svn st ^| findstr /R "^!"\`) do svn del "%%i %%j"
```

then

```
svn commit . -m test
```

It works for me. Thanks.