# How to autoremove folders/files from a SVN repo automatically?

Tags: svn, tree, directory

Im using SVN for the first time, so probably this is a basic question.

The app im using under svn, the problem is that one task of the application is to add/remove folders/files automatically; When i commit, i want to update the repository with the current folder tree.

I saw how to add all created files/folder, with `svn add -f myapp/*`, but i get an error if i delete a folder that was already in the repository: `svn: Directory '/myapp/folder' is missing`.

How can I tell SVN to remove missing folder/files from repo during commit?

I know svn has the `remove` command, but is kindly an headcache to use everytime i remove something.

**Update**: Thanks to jon's link, i found this command: `svn rm $( svn status [LOCAL_COPY_PATH] | sed -e '/^!/!d' -e 's/^!//' ) [LOCAL_COPY_PATH]` that fullfill my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `svn delete` rather than just deleting folders/files from the repo. That being said, it looks like someone wrote a script to do this:

[svn commit missing file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040125/svn-commit-missing-file-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure your commit, there's no way around it. SVN treats deleted files and deleted folders somewhat differently. If you delete a file within a directory, the folder will be marked as modified. If you delete the folder after that, you will have the problem above. Now this can happen, especially if you don't commit in a while.

My suggestion is to restore the folder first with svn update, properly delete with "svn rm", then commit.

Comment: I cant rely on `svn rm`. As said, my application itself add/remove elements, and working on my app to force it to use svn commands looks like a waste of time